# Issue with Graphviz on Python - Program terminated

Tags: python, anaconda, graphviz

I have been running a script on python to make a decision tree

```
from sklearn import tree
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model = model.fit(X,Y)
```

and then I wanted to visualize the result in a png file, so I ran the following

```
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydotplus
from IPython.display import Image  

dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(model, out_file=dot_data,filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True, leaves_parallel=False)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.create_png()
Image(graph.write_png("tree.png"))
```

I am using Anaconda, so i ran the following in the Anaconda prompt to install Pydotplus and Graphviz:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus
conda install graphviz
```

However, after this, I get the following error and I have no idea where it comes from

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-4578c1902391>", line 1, in <module>
graph.create_png()

  File "C:\Users\ferlandf\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1797, in <lambda>
lambda f=frmt, prog=self.prog: self.create(format=f, prog=prog)

  File "C:\Users\ferlandf\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 2032, in create
status, stderr_output))

InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 3221225477. stderr follows: []
```

Does someone have any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: As the [graphviz package docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) say, in order to render images you also need to install the actual Graphviz program and add its location to your system path - have you done that?

Comment: yes i did that. i also tried uninstalling and reinstalling in different orders but the problem was still here. But after doing nothing for a few hours, i tried again and for some reason i don't get, it worked...